# Android Support Libraries v27

Tags: android

I have an android question, I'm primarily a front end developer but I'm trying to build an Android project..

Android support libraries v27 doesn't seem to install into my extras/android folder

**Missing folders 27.0.x**

[image]

It shows as installed in the SDK manager.

**Showing as installed**

[image]

Also, when I change version to v25.0.0 in build.gradle deps, clean project and resync, the error still says it's missing design:27.0.2, not 25.0.0..

Is there some other cache or config file? I've searched for '27.0.2' in the entire project and no results..

Update:

Here is the defaultConfig section of the build.gradle:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25

    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 248
        versionName "0.9.80"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Dependencies looks like this:

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
     ...
      }
```

It's also using a private version of Maven (could this be the issue?)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url = "http://dl.bintray.com/..." }
    }
```

When I update the dependencies to 27.0.2 I get this:

**Already installed API 27**

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-2

Comment: Can you share your app level build.gradle here? please update in the question as well.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: that link doesn't have a download for version 27. Which leaves me no other way to download it than through the SDK manager, but that isn't working as I said.

Comment: @AnkitMehta: I should ask before I share the gradle file, I know that makes it harder to give me advice but will let you know asap. Is there anything in particular I can post from it that you think would help? For example any clarification on why Android Support libraries 27 seems to install but doesn't appear in my extras folder? (see new images above).

Comment: Edit: I've posted my default config in the hope that it helps.

Comment: You need to add Google's maven repo. This is described on the support lib website. I think that was since 25.3?

Answer (score 3):

Since 25.4.0 the support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. You do not need to download the support repository from the SDK Manager.

In your root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
             url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

For newer Gradle versions (I think 4+) you can just write `google()` as you would `jcenter()`.

See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Thanks @for3st, this worked. What is confusing is that there are 3 other blocks in the build.gradle that define 'repositories', therefore I thought we already had this covered. This did fix the issue.